# Why does 'return false' not prevent page reload on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I already tried this code but it does not prevent page reload on `onclick` function.  What should I do?  Did I miss something or is this a browser compatibility issue?

```
function track_specs() {
  $('button[name="delete_spec"]').each(function() { 
    this.onclick = null; 
    $(this).click(function () { 
      delete_specs($(this).data("id")); 
      return false; 
    }); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Are any of the 'delete_spec' buttons inside a `<form>` tag?   If you put an `alert` before the `return false`, does it get shown before the browser reloads?  If you temporarily comment the 'delete_specs' call, does it still reload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the code, can you try this? You don't need to loop through all the `<button>` tags which is a costly one. You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('button[name="delete_spec"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    delete_specs($(this).data("id")); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A `<button>` shouldn't initiate a page reload on click unless you have another click listener that reloads the page or maybe in your `delete_specs` function.

You could try this:

```
$(this).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

But I think you are explicitly reloading the page somewhere else (through `window.location = ...`).

Comment: FYI, a button in a form is a submit button by default if a specific type is not set. See [`<button type="">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes).

Comment: @Teemu Ah okay, I didn't realize this was in a form.